# rsync between two Ubuntu server 16 on mounted samba folders

Tags: permissions, vmware, rsync

I have two identical vmware servers with the following setup:

vmware1:
1x windows server 2012a - fileserver (10.10.10.10 = internal vmware net + 192.168.0.10 = external net)
1x Ubuntu server 16a - plex, rsync (10.10.10.20 = internal vmware net + 192.168.0.20 = external net)

vmware2:
1x windows server 2012b - fileserver (10.10.10.30 = internal vmware net + 192.168.0.30 = external net)
1x Ubuntu server 16b - plex, rsync (10.10.10.40 = internal vmware net + 192.168.0.40 = external net)

The windows server share media to the Ubuntu plex server on internal vmware lan (10.10.10.x) and are mounted with `fstab` - works perfect on plex.

Now I want to rsync all of my shares on ubuntu16a on vmware1 to ubuntu16b on vmware2.

Created root & John public ssh keys on A and transfered it to B and password free ssh login works fine.

The windows 2012A and 2012B both has a user called john with full rights to all of the plex shares.

ubuntu16a fstab:

```
//10.10.10.XX/archive1  /media/2012a/archive1  cifs  username=john,password=mypwd,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
//10.10.10.XX/archive2  /media/2012a/archive2  cifs  username=john,password=mypwd,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

ubuntu16b fstab:

```
//10.10.10.XX/archive1  /media/2012b/archive1  cifs  username=john,password=mypwd,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
//10.10.10.XX/archive2  /media/2012b/archive2  cifs  username=john,password=mypwd,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

When I run the rsync command from ubuntu16a:

```
rsync -a /media/2012a/archive1/ root@192.168.0.30:/media/2012b/archive1
```

the files transfer but I get:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/media/2012b/archive1/.": Permission denied (13) - Why is that ?
```

The aim with this configuration is to a have a backup site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mount both shares on both servers, then rsync could skip one layer (ssh) and work "locally":

```
rsync -a /media/2012a/archive1 /media/2012b/archive1
```

If it still gives same error, it may have problem with CIFS (allows it set timestamp in Linux manner?) or with permissions.

Comment: I removed "sec=ntlm  0  0" and added: "file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0" at the end of the mount and that seems to have solved the problem. Thanks